# Creating a secured rss feed with Zend_Feed

Tags: php, zend-framework, feed, zend-auth, zend-feed

I was wondering if it was at all possible to create a rss(or atom) feed with Zend_Feed that would be on a secured website (With Zend_Auth).

How would users be able to subscribe to my feed? 
How would feedreaders handle authentification? 
Is there any pitfalls I should be aware of (one I can think of is users who use outlook, IE, and other tools for there feeds)?

Hope I am clear enough. Thanks in advance!
ps: I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414373/securing-the-rss-feed-with-username-and-password-for-private-viewing) but its about .net and I do not see how it answers my questions.

edit: I would not mind a more general php answer to this question if its applicable to Zend also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am going to answer myself because one day someone might have the same questions. Its not really possible to do what I want, not necessarely because of the Zend Framework but mostly because of the hassle of serving rss over https and our secure login system.

I read a couple of blogs and found interresting info but really there is no way to make this solution viable for us (or for anyone I would guess unless its a custom rss reader wich I could never impose to my users).